# Rails mailer Connection refused - localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

ruby version 2.2.0
Rails 4.1.4
actionmailer- 4.1.4
mail - 2.5.4

I have met error logs below when input "Mailer.method.deliver" in rails c (development)

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:89:in `block in timeout'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `call'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
from (irb):4
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

Of course, I add mailer configuration (below) to development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "email",
  :password => "password",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

and after I debugged..

```
# mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb 
# before line: 112  

raise settings.to_s  #added
smtp.start(settings[:domain], settings[:user_name], settings[:password], settings[:authentication]) do |smtp_obj|
...
...
```

I could see settings hash has default variables(:symbol) and custom variables(:string) added from environments/development.rb.

```
RuntimeError: {:address=>"localhost", :port=>25, :domain=>"localhost.localdomain", :user_name=>nil, :password=>nil, :authentication=>nil, :enable_starttls_auto=>true, :openssl_verify_mode=>nil, :ssl=>nil, :tls=>nil, "address"=>"smtp.gmail.com", "port"=>587, "authentication"=>"plain", "user_name"=>"email", "password"=>"password", "enable_starttls_auto"=>true}
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:113:in `deliver!'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
from /Users/KimJaeseong/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry.
I had forgotten one information that I let you know.

I have seen a setting below about mailer configuration from stackoverflow answer.

```
# config/initializer/setup_mail.rb

if Rails.env != 'test'
  email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/smtp.yml"))
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = email_settings[Rails.env] unless email_settings[Rails.env].nil? 
end

# I say this [A] code
```

[A] code result in the bug above this question description.
(Adding "raise settings.to_s" to mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb before line 112 raise symbol and strings.)

I think the reason why [A] code happen this bug is smtp_settings(hash) merge! in initialize method from class SMTP (mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb).

```
class SMTP
  include Mail::CheckDeliveryParams

  def initialize(values)
    self.settings = { :address              => "localhost",
                      :port                 => 25, 
                      :domain               => 'localhost.localdomain',
                      :user_name            => nil,
                      :password             => nil,
                      :authentication       => nil,
                      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
                      :openssl_verify_mode  => nil,
                      :ssl                  => nil,
                      :tls                  => nil 
                    }.merge!(values)
  end
  ...
```

**Testing ruby hash merge method**

```
default_setting = {:address => "localhost", :port => 25}
custom_setting = {:address => "smtp.gmail.com", :port => 587} # or {"address" => "smtp.gmail.com", "port" => 587}
default_setting.merge(custom_setting) # result in default_setting = {:address => "localhost", :port => 25, "address" => "smtp.gmail.com", "port" => 587}
```

So I just have decided to add smtp_setting to application.rb with ENV["SMTP_EMAIL"], ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"]

Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

We use a Google Address on occasion for applications or testing. You may want to log in to the Google Account and make sure you have allowed the external application. This would be under account security.